# Genexus17 could not reach web server

Tags: genexus

I am following Udemy tutorials with Genexus 17 trial version.
After I create my first transaction, and click F5 to Execute/Deploy to cloud, it displays the following error:

> ========== DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) started ==========
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /nologo
> /p:Configuration=Release
> /p:FrameworkPath="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /v:q
> /m  "C:\Models\TravelAgency3\CSharpModel\build\LastBuild.sln" Success:
> DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (.NET Framework)
> ========== Web config update started ========== Updating web config ... Success: Web config update Building file gx_last_transfer.zip...
> Uploading 7 Kbytes Deploying website
> ========== Execution started ========== ... waiting for server ... error: Could not reach web server or something went wrong running your
> application at
> https://trialapps3.genexus.com/Idf34a868f535909f93e51fbc52ebdb90f/developermenu.html
> please try again.  Status code: 404 NotFound.. If the problem
> persists, follow the steps described in
> https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?49557 Failed: Execution Failed:
> Run Developer Menu

Comment: Does the issue persists after re run F5? Or after a full Rebuild?

Comment: Yes, it does persists.

Answer (score -1):

File developermenu.html is not deployed to cloud when "Short File Name" is not enabled in your Windows installation.
Anyway, the application seems to be well deployed.

There are three solutions:

1. What this html has is a link to each object of the KB, so what you can do is to include the name of the object to be executed in the URL.
   Example: https://trialapps3.genexus.com/Idf34a868f535909f93e51fbc52ebdb90f/customer.aspx
2. Another possibility is to create a Webpanel main (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7407,Main%20program%20property) that calls the rest of the objects (eg using a button or a link) and execute that main.
3. Perhaps the easiest is to edit Packages\rundotnet.config file including this line:

   *.html